# How to determine if last character is a dot and, if so, remove it

Tags: twig

I have a webform with an open text-field in which anything can be entered. I need to display that input verbatim in a sentence, as part of a block of text.

What I want to do is to check if the last character of that text field input is a dot, and if so, remove it. What I found so far is that you can use "|last" to find the last character, and I found how to replace characters with nothing, effectively removing them.

But I can't figure out how to make it conditional, so that it only does the replace if the last character in the string is a dot, and also that it only replaces that specific dot without touching potential other dots in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right the filter `last` will also return the last character of a string in `twig`. You can use this in any condition you want to, e.g.

```
{% if foo|last == '.' %}
    Foo has a dot
{% endif %}

{% if bar|last == '.' %}
    Bar has a dot
{% endif %}
```

To remove the last character you can just use the filter [slice](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/slice.html)

```
{% if foo|last == '.' %}
    {{ foo[:-1] }}
{% else %}
    {{ foo }}
{% endif %}


{% if bar|last == '.' %}
    {{ bar[:-1] }}
{% else %}
    {{ bar }}
{% endif %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/3x5jsu)

---

You could also remove the `if` - `endif` as follows

```
{{ foo|last == '.' ? foo[:-1] : foo }}
{{ bar|last == '.' ? bar[:-1] : bar }}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/vzjoo5)

Answer (score -1):

Using regexes when sending data server side when cleaning the input.
Or also in Javascript when sending the data

example server-side

```php
$input = 'Ciao. a tutti.';
// regex matching a dot only if last position
$pattern = '/\.$/i';
$clean_input = preg_replace($pattern, '', $input);
echo $input ." => " .$clean_input;
```

better regex that also strips (if present) trailing whitespaces:

```php
$pattern = '/\.\s*$/i';
```

EDIT:
in twig you can:

```
{% if input matches '{\.\s*$}' %}
   {# display the data without last dotremove last dot #}
{% endif %}
```

or also

```
{{ input | replace('/\.\s*$/', '') }}
```

Comment: Using regex for simple string actions is overkill imho